# Can not build android app react-native-vector-icons:releaseCompileClasspath

Tags: android, react-native

I use react-native-vector-icons with react-native-elements

The problem is that when I debug my app icons do not show up, and if I try to build release .apk
I get :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:releaseCompileClasspath'.
Could not find common.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/common/1.1.0/common-1.1.0.jar
Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.1.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.1.0/common-1.1.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

ok, the solution to this was ... funny

when you run build, build script must be downloaded from a repo, so the solution is to change URL/repo u r using when building

1 - open android/build.gradle and node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android/build.gradle
2 - in both files u shall see jcenter() function that gives URL to repo,
3 - to solve the problem, place google() function above jcenter() in both files(in repositories section, and in allprojects section of android/build.graddle)